# Running the multiple instances of same jupyter notebook without affecting each other's session

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab to run a script. I'd like the same script simultaneously with different variable settings. How can one do this?

Comment: start new jupyter notebook with environment variable and then read this into script, i have not tried this but should work.

Comment: Could you clarify more? From the title of your post it sounds like you'd be interested in nteract's [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill), or something along those lines. ([Here](https://arthought.com/colab-mlflow-and-papermill/) indicates papermill indeed works on Colab.) Usually you'd run execute things in turn and you time each if you need timing. However, you further go on to say you'd like to run it simultaneously which suggests you may be interested in [multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html). Plus are you hard-coding or passing in arguments?